# Tag <blablabla> Entry not supporting in Asp.Net Textbox

Tags: asp.net

Tag not supporting in Asp.Net Textbox (for example : I write `<something>` inside a Textbox then nothing works, everything breaks)

Clear ex: I have a Textbox in asp.net page and inside the textbox i wrote `<satyam>`. Then it is not working. but if i write in a normal way for example: " hello ", then evrything works fine.

Can you suggest me what's wrong?

Comment: When everything breaks, what is that error message that you are getting?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$txtDescription="...          <tr>

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: `<system.web><httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /></system.web>` Add this in web.config

Answer (score 0):

This was because .NET detected something in the entered text which looked like an HTML statement

You can also refer this link

[A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297679/A-potentially-dangerous-Request-Form-value-was-det

Comment: Thank you everyone...
ValidateRequest="false"
and <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> worked (y)